# Printing a single dimension array in user specified columns in C language

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to display the elements of an array in the number of columns that the user specifies. They decide how large the array is and how many columns it will be displayed in. Right now, I am printing the elements of the array in columns but, I have extra rows and columns with numbers that are not in the array. Thus if I select array size and column number as 5 3, I would hope to see:

```
1 3 5
2 4
```

Instead, I get something like:

```
1 3 5
2 4 107863456 
128976543 58764 896543221
5643217 90876543456 8976543
```

I am getting 3 columns with 4 rows. I do not know why this is happening. Here is the portion of my code that deals with creating columns, let me know if more code is needed (x is variable that holds array size, y holds number of columns):

```
void colDisplay(int *aPtr, int x, int y) {
    int i, j;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        aPtr[i] = rand()%5+1;
    }

    /*Trying to format display for number of columns used*/
    printf("Unsorted columns\n");
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            //printf("%d = %d ", (i*y)+j, aPtr[(i*y)+j]);
            printf("%d ", aPtr[(i*y)+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop constructs are not doing what you intend. You are executing a total of `x*y` print statements. When in fact you only ever want a total of `x` prints. Which also means your `aPtr` array access goes out of bounds and hence the garbage data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop is counting the columns correctly, but the outer loop is using `x` as a row count, instead of an item count. To fix the problem you can use a single loop that counts items, and outputs newlines at the correct times.

```
j = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < x; i++ )
{
    printf("%d ", aPtr[i] );
    j++;
    if ( j == y || i == x-1 )
    {
        printf( "\n" );
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the solution by @user3386109.

Also, the following change will help:

```
Original 'for' loop with j:
for(j = 0; j < y; j++)   
Modified code:
for (j = 0; (j < y) && (i*y+j < x); j++)
```

Reason: index = i*y+j may exceed x if (x % y != 0) i.e. if x (array size) is not integral multiple of y (display column size).

Answer (score 0):

Because of arrays index out of bound.

You should do the following:

```
 for(i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
   boolean isContinue = true;
    for(j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        int index = i*y+j;
        if(index==x){
            isContinue = false;
            break; 
        }

        printf("%d ", aPtr[(i*y)+j]);
    }
    if(!isContinue){
       break;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```